# Connecting to FTP, directory seems to be blank

Tags: macos, ftp

I need to transfer some files into a guest computer in VirtualBox, and I think FTP would be a good way, but am having trouble connecting the two "computers".

I tried running:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

then running:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet "
```

and grabbing the address returned that wasn't 127.0.0.1.

I even downloaded the [FTPD Enable app](http://www.troncept.com/lion-ftpd-enable/), but when I visit `ftp://192.168.1.119/` in a browser it's just an empty directory.

Is there a setting in Preferences -> Sharing I need to set, or is the FTP leading to a directory somewhere that might just be empty?

When going to higher level directories, (`ftp://192.168.1.119/../../../../../../../../../`), they all look the same.

I wouldn't think it should be necessary to install [OSX Server](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/) for this.

Comment: actually solved it based on comment from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110965/connect-to-ftp-server-in-finder-not-working, but I think might be useful to leave for others. have to connect like this: `ftp://username:password@192.168.1.119`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so to move files btwn host and guest (virtualbox) i was able to set up ftp on the host as noted above and access the host from the guest either via browser by doing:

```
ftp://username:password@192.168.1.119
```

Substituting username and password with my user/admin username and password.

OR (even better) simple from the command line:

```
$ ftp 192.168.1.119
Connected to 192.168.1.119.
220 192.168.1.119 FTP server (tnftpd 20100324+GSSAPI) ready.
Name (192.168.1.119:username): my_username
331 User my_username accepted, provide password.
Password:
User my_username logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

The the [commands within the ftp interface](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_ftp_through_command_line_mac_os_x) are mostly quite similar to bash/unix commands.

```
ftp> cd Sites/mzoo
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> cd mglitch
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> ls
500 Illegal PORT command rejected
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

Hey! What happened there? We have to go into passive mode:

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,119,194,210)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for '/bin/ls'.
total 1
-rw-r--r--   1 my_username  staff  12292 Jun 25 21:45 .DS_Store
rw-r--r--   1 my_username  staff    252 Jun  5 15:13 .htaccess
```

get will retrieve a single file and wget will get files matching request. for example:

```
ftp> lcd audio # changing to local directory "audio"
Local directory now /home/username/bla-bla-audio
ftp> mget *.mp3
```

Here's a [list if basic ftp commands](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html).

Command to turn off ftp on the host is:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```